# Is it possible that the MSDN example caused the resource leak?

Tags: c#, .net

I got a stream sample from the MSDN, and I double there is possible resource leak issue. For example, if there is exception happens at `readStream.ReadToEnd()` or other code lines, then is it possible that it would cause the resource leak for `HttpWebResponse\StreamReader`?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.maximumautomaticredirections(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public class Test
{
    // Specify the URL to receive the request.
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(args[0]);

        // Set some reasonable limits on resources used by this request
        request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
        request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;
        // Set credentials to use for this request.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine("Content length is {0}", response.ContentLength);
        Console.WriteLine("Content type is {0}", response.ContentType);

        // Get the stream associated with the response.
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        Console.WriteLine("Response stream received.");
        Console.WriteLine(readStream.ReadToEnd());
        response.Close();
        readStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend HttpClient for any new code.

Comment: It is another different  topic, currently we are focusing on the resource Leak possibilities for that MSDN example.

Comment: OK, I thought it was worthwhile mentioning though.

Comment: It is better to use `using` around `HttpWebResponse` and `Stream` objects. It will close and dispose. `using (Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream()) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

It's an example, not a good practice. It's optimised for clarity, not correctness. In general, MSDN samples *are not something to copy into your code*. They are usually too simple for real life (little error handling etc.) or too specific. I've even seen some that are pretty much wrong outright (e.g. the networking samples that assume a single TCP write on one side corresponds to a single TCP read on the other); all you can do is report those and perhaps comment on them.

However, the leak isn't necessarily a problem - it has no effect on the managed objects (there's no way to force the destruction of managed objects), and any unmanaged objects will be cleaned up eventually as well assuming they are all properly managed by their owner (e.g. a `SafeHandle` will dispose of the underlying handle automatically, if you forget to). If you want to understand that better, read up on .NET finalizers. In short, the finalizer will clean up the unmanaged resources if they haven't been cleaned up by an explicit `Dispose` (as with `using (stream) { ... }`).

Of course, there are cases where relying on the GC isn't just bad practice, but outright wrong. The most obvious example (and one I've seen many times in software in the wild) is forgetting to close an open file, and then trying to open it again with a file sharing clash. In the worst cases, it might not even be a deterministic error - perhaps some operations introduce enough memory pressure and take enough time for a finalizer to close the file *sometimes*, and the error only shows its ugly had rarely, and you got a very ugly bug that's hard to reproduce.

Going even further, there's no real requirement for a conforming implementation of .NET to include a garbage collector in the first place, or for the GC to work way you need it to. Say, a .NET runtime that allows your application's memory to grow until there's nowhere to grow and then throwing `OutOfMemoryException` would be perfectly legal (and for some kinds of applications, very useful). A good implementation will keep track of the managed resources, but unmanaged resources are always your responsibility - if it implements `IDisposable`, it's your job to call it (usually using a `using`). In a perfect .NET application, finalizers would *never* run - they're a safety net, and if you keep hitting the safety net, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Nice answer, I would add that the main problem is that GC will clean up unmanaged ressources, but you have no way to tell when it will clean them up, and that's a problem because you can't reuse a file or a socket until the previous one has effectively closed the underlying stream.

Comment: @MartinVerjans Sure, I've added some more details :)

Comment: Please note, if you are a circus artist stumbling in on this programming site, **do not** listen to Luaans last suggestion

Comment: Luaan , so it mean the leak in this MSDN example would not affect further more WebRequest and StreamReader  operations?   and this is totally different  from  forget closing the  file stream   , as that would block continuing  operating on the file.

Comment: @Jason Mostly, yes. If you tried hard, it *is* possible for `WebRequest` to exhaust the available TCP connections, but it's not something you'd commonly find in a desktop application. Trying to open the same file twice (in conflicting manner) *is* something you see all the time. With something like `WebRequest`, you need to exclusively block hundreds of objects before things break, while for the file you only have the one so collisions are a lot more likely. The first case means "you're outside of where you can pretend things are simple", the second "this is *your* fault" :)

Comment: @Default It might be more useful if you addressed the issue you see directly, rather than appealing to the readers :) Are you suggesting that disposing of unmanaged resources should be the exceptional case, and you should just let them linger until a finalizer comes around *unless* you have a good reason to dispose of them earlier?

Comment: @Luaan haha, no, sorry, I was only referring to the last line completely out of context - If a circus artist does hit a safety net I think they are doing something right (compared to not hitting it). If they look at the complete answer they should definitely follow your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 3):

The example indeed lacks proper disposing of resources, as examples often do. This is the fault of the writer who preferred brevity above good coding practices.

The `HttpWebRequest`, `Stream` and `StreamReader` should all have enclosing `using` blocks.